# django filtering on datetime = None

Tags: django, aggregates

I have a table with metadata on fieldmeasurement in which a fields 'startDate' is of type datetime. The value can be empty, when no info is available. I would like to run some statistics on this field, and get min and max value (i.e. the oldest measurements available over all records). No problem for the Max, but for Min the aggregation returns None (the value in empty fields).

So my idea is to filter these records from the queryset, before running the aggregate. I cannot find how to do this.

I have tried

```
oldestdate = Measurement.object.filter(startDate__isNull=True).aggregate(Min('startDate'))['startDate__min']
```

Any idea what's wrong, or how to do this?

EDIT:
some more testing reveals that:

```
Measurement.objects.filter(startDate_isnull=True) -> only records with startDate = None
Measurement.objects.filter(startDate_isnull=False) -> all records, also the ones with startDate = None. 
Measurement.objects.exclude(startDate__isnull=False) -> only records with startDate = None
Measurement.objects.exclude(startDate__isnull=True) -> shows all records (also startDate == None)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
oldestdate = Measurement.objects.filter(
    startDate__isnull=True).aggregate(min_date=Min('startDate'))

# or to make it small:

oldestdate = Measurement.objects.filter(startDate__isnull=True
    ).aggregate(min_date=Min('startDate'), max_date=Max('startDate'))
```

Comment: It does not work. Fields with None are not filtered out.  oQuery = WindWaveFile.objects.all()  oQuery.exclude(startDate__isnull=True).aggregate(Min('startDate'))['startDate__min'].strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"). The strftime raises an exception because of that (error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime' )

Comment: correct, in the version I posted before, the strftime part was not yet added. However, the original problem remains, the filter does not recognize None.

Comment: ass a bypass I now filter everything since a certain date (10years ago) and this works (and I can use the strftime). But it is not a clean solution (as I should never be 100% sure that all dates are younger than 10years)

Comment: Try to test like this `oldestdate = Measurement.objects.filter(startDate__isnull=True)`, if None is filtered or not. In that way will know what's the problem

Comment: other function is change when django upgrade to latest version

Comment: Good, next if you want to debug something just  divide it and test it one by one until all are working :)

Comment: thanks catherine. some more testing reveals that startDate_isnull=True shows only records with startDate = None, but startDate_isnull=False does not do the opposite. i.e. it returns all records, also the ones with startDate = None. But to my surprise switching to exclude does the opposite. exclude(startDate__isnull=False) shows only records with startDate=None, while exclude(startDate__isnull=True) shows all records (also startDate == None)

Comment: yeah filter() and exclude() do the opposite thing